# Access to controls of a Form opened inside a tab

Tags: vb.net, winforms, tabs

I'm having problem accessing my winform controls when I open it inside a tab.

I have Form1 and Form2. Form1 has a tab, and I open form2 as below:

```
Dim ff As New Form2

ff.TopLevel = False
ff.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
ff.Width = TabControl1.TabPages(tabs).Width
TabControl1.TabPages(tabs).Controls.Add(ff)
```

Everything is fine but I can not access Form2 controls from Form1.

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the form visible when you add it to the control collection:

```
TabControl1.TabPages(tabs).Controls.Add(ff)
ff.Visible = True
```

Since you have the declaration in Form1 (presumably), you can just access the controls collection directly:

```
For Each c As Control in ff.Controls
  ' do something with c
Next
```

If "ff" is not declared at the form level, then you can assign the name property to the form and then find it through the control collection:

```
Dim ff As New Form2
ff.Name = "ff"
```

Then later:

```
Dim ff As Form2
If TabControl1.TabPages(tabs).Controls.ContainsKey("ff") Then
  ff = TabControl1.TabPages(tabs).Controls("ff")
End If
```

Comment: So you are not concerned that OP is trying to add a Form to ControlCollection... :)

Comment: @Neolisk Not really.  Form comes from control.  It's probably *better* to use a UserControl, but it's not the end of the world either.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but it throws an exception if you try to add a form into ControlCollection like that. If OP's code is working fine, we are probably missing a point.

Comment: @Neolisk The OP's code has TopLevel = False and FormBorderStyle = None, it should act pretty much like a UserControl at that point.

Comment: @Neolisk the only thing unique about this situation is that the OP is Embedding his form in a TabControl, otherwise it is the same question that has been asked a myriad of times the past few weeks about how to access another forms controls.

Comment: Honestly, did not know about this `TopLevel` trick, but the problem remains - this code does not add anything to the tab, even though it stopped throwing an exception. Works fine with a UserControl. Did you test it in VS?

Comment: @Neolisk set the Visible property to true

Comment: @MarkHall: yep, that did the trick (that's the part I missed). I also removed `FormBorderStyle` statement and got amazing visual effects - an MDI host inside a TabControl. Thanks for enlightening me. To celebrate, everybody gets a +1 in this thread. :)

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. @LarsTech, I do use the ff.show(), sorry that I missed that one. I used your suggestion and it worked perfectly ( ff.name="ff" when creating the instance and use it later on ).  I appreciate your help.  One quick question though that I need to ask. The nature of this application is Order Management and we want to be able to open Form2( lets say this is our general entry/update form ) in multiple tabs in one window to be able to manage them in parallel. Is this approach good ? Or do you guys recommend using usercontrols ?

Comment: @user1121190 For what you are doing, a UserControl probably makes more sense since you aren't using a form to be a form.